# Absolute Div auto Height not working

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS3 tabs (Without JS) and having a big problem.

I am trying to make auto height of absolute div so that it can expand or shrink height accordinly but for some reasons it is not working.

I tried to give 100% height to my html,body but still not working. Without putting in more words, [Here is JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4n8uaz/).

Here is my relevant CSS:

```
.content {
    background: #3404FC;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* padding: 10px 40px; */
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

As you can see blue background is height so why it is not taking auto height. I tried 100% but it is not working at all.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.content div{
  position: relative;
```

}/**instead of position: absolute;

you can selected div visibility: visible:
and none-selected div visibility hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've set the height to 100% of the parent div, in this case `content` it won't have a height. The reason is, all of your child elements are positioned `absolute`. This makes the elements go out of the normal flow making the height of the parent div to 0px.

Comment: So what's the solution to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**

```
body,html,.tabs{height:100%;}
```

Because you are using margin in tabs, its height will be more thant 100%.